# Using I18n markdown strings in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, haml, markdown

I have localised markdown strings in my language file, and I am looking for a cleaner way to do the following in HAML:

```
#text_for_something
  :markdown
    #{ t(:text_in_markown) }
```

Or, equivalently:

```
#text_for_something!= Maruku.new( t(:text_in_markown) ).to_html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not what you were thinking of but you could just add the following helper to `helpers/application_helper.rb`

```
def render_md(key)
    Maruku.new( t(key) ).to_html
end
```

and then just use it in your HAML like this:

```
#text_for_something!= render_md :text_in_markown
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing something similar for the i18n of [my Rails Tutorial sample app](https://github.com/paulfioravanti/sample_app).  Not sure if it matters, but I used [RDiscount](https://github.com/rtomayko/rdiscount) to render Markdown.

In summary, I file each i18n-ized markdown file under a **controller/action** directory under **config/locales**, and determine which page needs to be rendered in the controller.  For example, in the case of a simple About page, here is where the `:en` markdown file is located here:

**config/locales/static_pages/about/about.en.md**

```
About Us
========

Some more markdown text...
```

The path to the file to be rendered gets determined in the controller and assigned to `@page`, then the file itself gets rendered out in the relevant HAML partial:

**app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb**

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :localized_page

  def about
    # ...
  end

  # ...

  protected

    def localized_page
      locale = params[:locale]
      @page = "#{Rails.root}/config/locales/#{controller_name}/"\
              "#{action_name}/#{action_name}.#{locale}.md"
    end
end
```

**app/views/static_pages/about.html.haml**

```
= render 'static_page', title: t('.about_us'), page: @page
```

**app/views/static_pages/_static_page.html.haml**

```
- provide(:title, title) if title
:markdown
  #{render file: page}
```